# Google Distance Matrix API Alternatives?

Tags: google-maps, matrix, distance

Can you recommend alternatives for the Google Distance Matrix API?
This service is great but has some serious quota limitations and the Terms of use are also pretty tough.

Thanks!

Comment: I tried MapQuest, it is a great alternative for US, sadly the information of other countries is still poor. Another good point in favor to MapQuest is that it is really flexible and free.

Answer (score 9):

MapQuest RouteMatrix is pretty much the same thing: http://www.mapquestapi.com/directions/

Comment: MapQuest is starting to charge for their API usage. They also offer a similar service using OpenStreetMaps but in my experience the free offering struggles to find many address.

Answer (score 6):

Bing's Route Data API may be an alternative you can consider - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701718.aspx

Answer (score 5):

<strike>I'm not sure if they have the same functionality, but DeCarta ( http://www.decarta.com/ ) has some nice map API stuff for routing / display.</strike>

Otherwise you could go for open source stuff like PostGIS with OpenStreetMaps or openrouteservice ( http://openrouteservice.org/ ) there are routing libraries, although I haven't used them extensively myself, so I'm not sure what they have to offer.

Comment: http://www.decarta.com/  301 redirects to uber.com now 

Comment: would recommend graphhopper then

Answer (score 3):

Many developers have been able to do this with the Bing Maps REST routing service http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701705.aspx. It requires a bit more development but works well. Here is an example: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Bing-Maps-trip-optimizer-c4e037f7

Answer (score 3):

The GraphHopper Directions API includes a [Matrix API](https://graphhopper.com/api/1/docs/matrix/). Based on OSM data and very fast. Comes with a [JS demo](https://github.com/graphhopper/directions-api-js-client#graphhopper-matrix-api) and a [Java client](https://github.com/graphhopper/directions-api-java-client). Note: I'm the author.

Also we allow all use cases.

Answer (score 0):

Traveltimeplatform. Just named differently - http://docs.traveltimeplatform.com/reference/time-filter/