# get distance between two places

Tags: java, openstreetmap

I actually am trying to find the distance between two places, I am new to this. I came to know about openstreetmap. But I am not sure what to do.

I found a traveling salesman application that uses osm to route. 
But here my question is how to get a osm between places .e.g. "http://www.openstreetmap.org/api/0.6/map?bbox=10,30,10,30" this gives me the map of the box (10,30,10,30) .. but if I want to get the map between leeds and sheffield what should be my query.

Or is there any other way to find the distance.(As I am a student I want some open source way for my academic project..)

please suggest..

Comment: What distance? The linear distance or the routing distance?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6163136/google-distance-matrix-api-alternatives

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For calculating the routing distance between two places you can use one of the various [online](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing/online_routers) or [offline](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing/offline_routers) routers. There is also a list of [various information for routing developers](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing#Developers) containing a list of libraries and other information.

If you have to obtain the location of a specific address before doing the actual routing you can use [Nominatim](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim).

Comment: Thank you so much, from the online router link you provided I found mapquest and used the routeMatrix to get the distance between two places..

Answer (score 3):

You should consider implementing this by yourself.

First, I suggest you to use the [Overpass API](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API) to do your queries.

Then implement [this algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) over the ways you get from the Overpass API :)

Comment: I am not verymuch used to web application .. can you please tell me how to use overpass query to get a xml file as output

Comment: In order to develop your queries, I suggest[Overpass turbo](http://overpass-turbo.eu). This tool has a really nice gui and it has several examples and explanations. Also take a look at the first link I posted in my answer

Comment: Sure, but not to calculate the routing distance. The Overpass API is just for obtaining raw data directly out of OSM's database. It cannot post-process this data itself.