# google distance matrix additional quota pricing

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-distancematrix-api

We are using Google Distance matrix API to calculate distances between all places & user’s location

our expected users count is 20000 & places count is 10,000

So, total will be minimum 20,000*10,000 =2,00,00,000 requests minimum for distance matrix API

also user can search multiple time places.

So per user Search 10,000 requests will go to calculate user's distance with each place.
& user can search multiple times.

So requests will be huge for each user.

Should  We use Google distance Matrix free API or purchase quota for MAPS API FOR WORK?

Answer (score 0):

The limits to Google Distance Matrix API is the following

Users of the free API:

```
- 100 elements per query.
- 100 elements per 10 seconds.
- 2500 elements per 24 hour period.
```

Google Maps API for Work customers:

```
- 625 elements per query.
- 1000 elements per 10 seconds.
- 100 000 elements per 24 hour period.
```

If you say there will be 10k queries per customer that seems far the limit of even the daily Distance Matrix limit of queries from a single workstation. **You need to go with the Work customers package.**

**More information here:**
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distancematrix/

For those wanting to leverage the **Google Distance Matrix API** I shared some **code samples in VBA** here:
http://www.analystcave.com/excel-calculate-distances-between-addresses/

Comment: is there any alternative for Google Distance Matrix API.?

Comment: Not that I know of - might want to research this. There are always work-arounds like using proxy servers (would have to have a lot of those), however, this would go against Google's policy. If this is a commercial project I would definitely recommend Google Distance Matrix for Work customers.

Comment: For alternatives see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6163136/google-distance-matrix-api-alternatives/